# How To Pass An Object To A Reveal Modal Pop-Up Window?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to use the Reveal Modal jQuery plug-in with my Rails 3.0.3 application.

What I want to do is create a child object from a parent object's index page. Right now I have links that pass the parent's id to the child controller's new method and then open the child's  new.html.erb , like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Add an entry', new_entry_path(:course_id => course.id) %>
```

What I would like to do is open a modal containing a form for creating a new child object.

The Reveal plug-in requires "data-reveal-id" be present in the link tag, e.g.:

```
`<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>`
```

How/can I do this using Rails helper function like link_to?

Thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will error out:

```
<%= f.submit  :reveal-id => "myModal" %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Add an entry', new_entry_path(:course_id => course.id),:reveal-id => "myModal" %>
```

Try the following instead:

```
<%= f.submit  "data-reveal-id" => "myModal" %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Add an entry', new_entry_path(:course_id => course.id),"data-reveal-id" => "myModal" %>
```

That will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used reveal recently and this is how it worked for me :-

```
=link_to "Sign Up", signup_path, :class=> "buttonForModal"

.Modal.reveal-modal
  Things you want in your modal window goes here
```

I was using javascript to load the modal window

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.buttonForModal').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.Modal').reveal();
  });
});
```

It is better to use js instead of "data-reveal-id"

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't understand .Modal.reveal-modal - it looks like CSS?