# Render html.erb (not partial) in other html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm quite new to Rails and trying to make app with Foundation framework. The problem is with modal window.

I have an `index.html.erb` file in `views/users` folder, generated by scaffold.
Also there is a `new.html.erb` file in the same folder.

I want to open `../users/new` link in modal window on index page.

I used examples in [Reveal (Foundation Documentation)](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html), put `new.html.erb` file content in:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
.
.
</div>
```

Also, add to New User link "href" attribute.

```
<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path, 'data-reveal-id' => 'myModal' %>
```

as was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729223/how-to-pass-an-object-to-a-reveal-modal-pop-up-window).

Now I need to render `new.html.erb` in `index.html.erb`, cause I need this code just before /body tag, as described in Foundation Docs.

I've tried to render it as partial, but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do it, without double `new.html.erb` as `_new.html.erb` and inserting it as partial in `index.html.erb`?

I don't think, that RoR with all there's "Write less code!" stuff, doesn't have the way for do it without code duplicating.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the new action as it is, though you can put your form in one partial, use across new and your action to generate form in modal.

On Page load you can use _form partial.

You can use ajax to generate the form for the model if you want on fly, this can be use for edit as well as new.

Step1 :link_to "your action path", remote: true, id: "abc"

Step2: your action path should return html of the form using render to string

Step3: now using jquery ajax success of $("#abc") replace your model inner content with the form.

And use the create action for both ajax and postback.

Code is DRY.

Let me know if you need the code.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Ajax part of your answer is still unclear for me.
But I've used your `_form` suggestion.

So, my code looks like this:
`<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path, 'data-reveal-id' => 'new-user-modal' %>
<div id="new-user-modal" class="reveal-modal">
<%= render 'form' %>
</div>`

Also it didn't work until I add `@user = User.new` to `users_controller.rb` in index part.
`  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end`